# Andengine sound only works sometimes

Tags: android, audio, andengine

I have a Sound loaded in the onCreateResources method.

```
try {
    shield = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(this.getMusicManager(), this, "shield.ogg");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

shield.setVolume(1.0f);
shield.setLooping(true);
```

When i play the sound the first time it works fine, however, the following times i play it is seems random if it works or not.

i use `shield.play();` to play the sound and `shield.stop();` to stop it again.
When it doesnt work i get the following in the log.

> AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
>
> Error creating AudioTrack

Comment: If i set looping to false, then it plays everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Using Music when you play background music, it will be control long play, repeat..
Using Sound when you play a short audio, example when press button, or shoot..etc
Here the my same code using both of them:

```
public static void controlBgAudio(boolean play, boolean repeat) {
    Music ms = ResourceManager.getInstance().audioBgMusic;
    if (play) {
        if (ms.isReleased()) {
            ms.resume();
        } else {
            ms.play();
        }
    } else {
        if (ms.isPlaying()) {
            ms.pause();
        } else {
            ms.stop();
        }
    }

    if (repeat) {
        ms.setLooping(true);
    } else {
        ms.setLooping(false);
    }
}

public static void controlShootAudio(boolean play, boolean repeat) {
    Sound ms = ResourceManager.getInstance().audioShoot;
    if (play) {
        if (ms.isReleased()) {
            ms.resume();
        } else {
            ms.play();
        }
    } else {
        if (ms.isLoaded()) {
            ms.pause();
        } else {
            ms.stop();
        }
    }

    if (repeat) {
        ms.setLooping(true);
    } else {
        ms.setLooping(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the MusicFactory for sound effects. It is strictly for music.
You are supposed to use the SoundFactory.

Here is an example:

```
Sound sound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(getSoundManager(), this, "sound.wav");
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the MusicFactory did the same thing as SoundFactory. It just allowed sounds longer than 5 seconds. Anyways, this gave me the same outcome. I still get random errors where the sound doesnt play